# html single radio button

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

Right now i have multiple radio buttons.But on select of one of the  radio button it should display a text box and on unselect it should hide the radio button. Right now on selecing i can show the textbox but on selecting other radio button i am unable to hide this textbox. SO how do i hide the textbox.

```
<div class="g three-twelfths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType" value="Had a baby or adopted a child" <cfif p_event_type eq "Had a baby or adopted a child">checked="checked"</cfif>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Had a baby or adopted a child
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g four-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType" value="Got married or entered into domestic partnership" <cfif p_event_type eq "Got married or entered into domestic partnership">checked="checked"</cfif>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Got married or entered into domestic partnership
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g four-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType2"  onclick="return checkselected();" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Other
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g seven-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole" style="visibility:hidden;" id="txtbox1">
    <cfinput type="text" name="EventType" id="txtbox" disabled="false" />
</div>
```

```
function checkselected(){
    var div_ref = document.all("txtbox1");
    div_ref.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: in your code i can't find out text box .?

Answer (score 1):

You can write other function that set the text box visibility to hidden, and call it when other radio button be clicked.

Other better way is listen to event `change` on radio buttons (or just the "Others" radio button) and show/hide the textbox depend on selected value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple problem and can easily be solved by as mentioned by @thanhdx. But you need to improve your syntax by a huge margin. It is generally a frowned upon practice to bind event listeners in html. You can easily do that in javascript `document.getElementById`.

Then after obtaining all checkboxes and adding event listeners to each of them. You can use the this object obtained in the callback of the click event ot check what element was clicked and based on that can change the visibility.

I have created a pen for this purpose you can refer that https://codepen.io/codebhendi/full/ZEGEBxy.

Also a piece of advice never have multiple elements with same ids. That is never a good practice.

Comment: This should be a comment but @shubham9182 is not yet worthy of making any.  To help him on his way, I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> try using this

```
<div class="g three-twelfths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType" value="Had a baby or adopted a child" <cfif p_event_type eq "Had a baby or adopted a child">checked="checked"</cfif>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Had a baby or adopted a child
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g four-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType" value="Got married or entered into domestic partnership" <cfif p_event_type eq "Got married or entered into domestic partnership">checked="checked"</cfif>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Got married or entered into domestic partnership
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g four-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole">
    <div class="field">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" id="EventType2"  onclick="return checkselected();" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Other
    </div>
</div>
<div class="g seven-tenths palm-one-whole lap-one-whole" style="display: none;" id="txtbox1">
    <input type="text" name="EventType" id="txtbox" disabled="false" />
</div>
```

```
function checkselected(){

    var div_ref = document.getElementById("txtbox1");
    div_ref.style.display = "block";
}
```